# How to transition a ng-view (fade for ex) so that one can't see the page building on iPad?

Tags: angularjs, transition, angularjs-ng-click

When the user tp a ng-click which opens a page (ng-view), I can see the construction of the destination page for a fraction of second. How can I fix the "flickering"? I would like to keep the source page, and fade once the destination dom is ready.
Any idea?